# SQL join Query Not selecting appropriate data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables `tblStockManagement`, `tblFolding` and `tblClient`.

In my `tblStockManagement` table I am using `client_id` (from the `tblClient` table) as a foreign key and `FoldingID` (from the `tblFolding` table) as a foreign Key.

Now I am selecting data from `tblStockManagement` (name of project from tblClient and name of folding from tblFolding) but it is not working according to my need.

Below is the query that I used to select data from `tblStockManagement`.

```
SELECT 
    tblClient.ProjectName, tblClient.Client_ID, 
    tblFolding.Name, tblFolding.FoldingID 
FROM 
    tblStockManagement 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblClient ON tblStockManagement.Client_ID=tblClient.Client_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblFolding ON tblStockManagement.Client_ID=tblFolding.FoldingID  
WHERE 
    tblStockManagement.quantity > 0
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: in tblStockManagement table data is showing fine look there is Client_id 1 do not have Folding_id 1 again but in result it shows client_id 1 has again Folding_id 1

Comment: i am just showing name of project instead of client_id and name of folding instead of folding id in result window

Comment: Please provide the data you expect to see.  What should those four result columns look like?  What is the structure of the tblClient table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to change this:

```
tblFolding ON tblStockManagement.Client_ID=tblFolding.FoldingID
```

to this:

```
tblFolding ON tblStockManagement.FoldingID=tblFolding.FoldingID
```

It's a guess because we don't how how your data model is meant to work.

Comment: In future you need to give us an _example_ of the data you expect to see.